# Enable/disable javascript using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

For some reason, I've to disable javascript for Firefox (Manually, we do by following steps mentioned http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/javascript-settings-for-interactive-web-pages#w_enabling-and-disabling-javascript). How can this be achieved by Selenium WebDriver using Ruby?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here. Can you try passing `false` in when you instantiate the driver?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't seem to cover that case in the documentation, and that was my only guess.

Comment: @TravisJ yes,it is possible. check my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, It is possible. But a different way. You first need to look into the link

- [`Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile #[]=(key, value)`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Firefox/Profile.html#[]%3D-instance_method).
- [`JavaScript settings`](http://preferential.mozdev.org/preferences.html)

Once you would visit the link,try the below code :

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile["javascript.enabled"] = false

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox, :profile => profile)

profile
# => #<Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile:0x89c7568
#     @additional_prefs=
#      {"javascript.enabled"=>false, "webdriver_firefox_port"=>7055},
#     @extensions=
#      {:webdriver=>
#        #<Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Extension:0x89c6488 # !> previous definition of proxy= was here
#         @path=
#          "/home/kirti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension/webdriver.xpi",
#         @should_reap_root=true>},
#     @load_no_focus_lib=false,
#     @model=nil,
#     @native_events=false,
#     @secure_ssl=false,
#     @untrusted_issuer=true>
```

Once your browser window will be opened up through the above code,then check the *Preferences* from ***Edit->Preferences->content***,then you would see that ***Enable JavaScript:*** option is unchecked.

[image: Enable JavaScript:]

Comment: @grm My pleasure to help you.. I spent 1 hours to find the second linked docs.. :))

Comment: If you are using a remote driver, the capabilities has a `:javascript_enabled` option you can set.